# capture audio from google recognizer intent

Tags: java, android, audio-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: Voice Recording and saving audio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905337/android-voice-recording-and-saving-audio)

I need to capture the audio signal from the `RecognizerIntent`.
Right now, I'm doing something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak");
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, defaultLocale);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 1);
i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, new Long(1000));
```

And I tried to create a class using the `MediaRecorder` to get the audio signal but it doesn't work. I really need to get the signal.